# Parsing images from website in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to parse images into a UITableViewCell through a website. I can easily parse one image, but I am trying parse different multiple images.I have some ideas on how I would accomplish this, but I was wondering what will be the simplest and best way to perform such a task.I doubt this helps, but the icon.jpg are named like this 1_icon,2_icon ect... Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {

mydata = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/uploads/1_icon.jpg"]];
myimage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:mydata];
_imageToDisplay.image=myimage;
self.tableview.delegate = self;
self.tableview.dataSource = self;




[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myimage];

return cell;
}
```

updated.m

```
 _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
int numberOfIcons=30;

for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfIcons; i++){
    [_imagesArray addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/uploads/%d_icon.jpg", i]]]]];
    NSLog(@"%d",numberOfIcons);
```

updated .h

```
     NSMutableArray *_imagesArray;
     NSArray*array;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preload all of the images in an array and reference them when the cell is created. This will prevent you from loading the image from the web every time a cell is created.

In viewDidLoad:

```
_imagesArray = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfIcons; i++){
  [array addObject:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/uploads/%d_icon.jpg", i]]]]];
}
```

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[_imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Comment: Sorry,I was trying to implement this and it didn't work out too well.I might of misinterpreted your code. I updated my code and I was wondering if you can tell me what you think?Really appreciate it.

Comment: -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]' I switched the values to numberoficons=34 and i=34 to make sure the object isnt nil.I believe it is this line that is causing the error "cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[_imagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]; "

Comment: Try setting the return value of numberOfRowsInSection to _imagesArray.count and reload the tableview data after filling the array.